# How to calculate total time difference for rows with same name using a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with Patient names and Dates. For example:

```
Column A=[1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002]
Column B=['03/12/2009', '03/12/2009', '04/01/2011', '05/01/2010', '08/02/2011', '10/03/2012', '05/12/2010', '07/02/2011', '09/03/2012', '14/02/2013']
```

For each patient name, I want to calculate the total length of time between the first and final date. I thought to perform this via a pandas df, but I can't complete my code to match the total time for each patient. This is what I have tried so far:

```
Patient_Dates = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Data.xlsx',
               sheet_name='Sheet 2', header=0, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "B:C")
Patient_Dates_new=Patient_Dates.iloc[3:len(Patient_Dates)]
Patient_Dates_new.columns = ['Patient_ID','Dates']
```

How can I calculate the total time in days for each patient? Here below is part of my excel file[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, the DataFrame is like

```
Patient_ID  Dates
0   1000    2009-03-12
1   1000    2009-03-12
2   1001    2011-04-01
3   1001    2010-05-01
4   1001    2011-08-02
5   1002    2012-10-03
6   1002    2010-05-12
7   1002    2011-07-02
8   1002    2012-09-03
```

```py
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df['days'] = df.groupby(['Patient_ID'])['Dates'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

output

```
Patient_ID  Dates   days
0   1000    2009-03-12  0 days
1   1000    2009-03-12  0 days
2   1001    2011-04-01  458 days
3   1001    2010-05-01  458 days
4   1001    2011-08-02  458 days
5   1002    2012-10-03  875 days
6   1002    2010-05-12  875 days
7   1002    2011-07-02  875 days
8   1002    2012-09-03  875 days
```

---

Alternatevily you can use

```py
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
grouped = df.groupby(['Patient_ID'])
op = []
for name, group in grouped:
    elapsed_day = group['Dates'].max() - group['Dates'].min()
    op.append([name, elapsed_day])

df_new = pd.DataFrame(op, columns=['Patient_ID', 'elapsed_day'])

df_new
```

output

```
Patient_ID  elapsed_day
0   1000    0 days
1   1001    458 days
2   1002    875 days
```

Comment: Thank you Epsi95. When I run your first line, I get the following error: ```<ipython-input-30-b92cb9767a99>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead```

Comment: Can you try the alternative method, the error is not clear to me

Comment: the error is due to operating on a view of the original data. Cut the dependency by doing `df = Patient_Dates.iloc[3:len(Patient_Dates)].copy()` (the `.copy()` makes sure `df` is a proper DataFrame not just a view of another DF).

Comment: Hi again, that's really great, thank you so much!. It worked very well!.

Comment: I have one last question!. Do you know how can I plot Patient_ID versus Days for each patient (i.e once for each patient)? Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 1):

Using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html),[apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) ,you can get your desired result,

```
df['Column B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column B'])

result = df.groupby(by='Column A')['Column B'].apply(lambda g: g.max() - g.min())
pd.merge(df,result,on='Column A',how='left',suffixes=['','_diff'])
```

output:

```
Column A    Column B    Column B_diff
0   1000    2009-03-12  0 days
1   1000    2009-03-12  0 days
2   1001    2011-04-01  458 days
3   1001    2010-05-01  458 days
4   1001    2011-08-02  458 days
5   1002    2012-10-03  875 days
6   1002    2010-05-12  875 days
7   1002    2011-07-02  875 days
8   1002    2012-09-03  875 days
```

Comment: Thank you once again!

Comment: One last question. How can I take the term "days" out of my third column above? I try to do some statistics using this dataframe, and the term "days" does not allow me to do the calculations.

Comment: `merged_df['Column B_diff'].dt.days` should work

Comment: Welcome, do consider to upvote if my answer helped you : )

Comment: Just a quick question, the above command takes days off but eliminates Column A and B. Is there a way to keep all my Columns at the same time that I eliminate "days"?

Comment: Just assign your values back to column, something like `merged_df['Column B_diff']=merged_df['Column B_diff'].dt.days` and then you can access your `merged_df`